# Traffic theory and queueing delay

Tags: queueing-theory

I was reading this wikipedia article on traffic theory https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fundamentals_of_Transportation/Traffic_Signals. And it seems to outline an equation that computes the time a car stays in a queue behind a light

```
t = (p*r)/(1-p)
```

Where `t` is the queueing delay, `p` is `arrival_rate / departure_rate` and `r` is red time.

This seems to imply that when the rate of incoming traffic is higher than the rate of outgoing traffic, the resulting queueing delay is fixed.  How can this be true? Won't the queue keep getting bigger and bigger if cars approach the intersection faster than they leave?

---

I'm not sure what tag to use for this question, so I apologize if the tags don't not fit the question.

Comment: Something seems weird there. The departure rate should equal the arrival rate, I believe, since the intersection doesn't create or destroy cars. Usually in queuing models $\rho$ is the arrival rate divided by the *service rate*; I wonder if they meant something like that?

Comment: I don't think I have the right intuition for this, can you explain why arrival rate should be equal to the departure rate?

Comment: If 100 cars per hour enter the intersection (on average), then 100 cars per hour must leave the intersection (on average), because cars aren't being created or destroyed at the intersection. The same is true of other queuing systems like $M/M/1$—even though the timing of a given customer's journey through the system is affected by the queue wait time and the service time, in steady state the average number of customers leaving the system per unit time is the same as the average number arriving.